# AWS Lambda to install node custom module

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, node-modules

I am using only one node package is [rrvideo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rrvideo) with taking about 400 MB of node_modules disk space. the issue is it takes more than 250 MB and due to that it not allowed to upload my project

I see rrvideo is using puppeteer as one of the dependency and that take 350 MB of disk space.

Can someone help us how we can setup this module on AWS Lambda or we can use any other ways to setup this rrvideo package to run on aws Lambda

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using traditional lambda function with the limit of 250 MB, you could consider using new ones, that use [container images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-images.html) which provide **10 GB** of space. From [aws](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/12/aws-lambda-now-supports-container-images-as-a-packaging-format/):

> You can now package and deploy AWS Lambda functions as a container image of up to **10 GB**. This makes it easy to build Lambda based applications using familiar container tooling, workflows, and **dependencies**.